# Why does "grunt serve:dist" render a different view than "grunt serve:dist"?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm a newbie with Yeoman and Grunt, and i had experience a big deal with the style-sheets after doing "grunt serve:dist".

It changed the font width, added some padding in the header and practically broke completely a table, i have no idea where to start debugging at, but i believe it does find the CSS, because the font style does change, and it is reading the JS, i put some console.log() to see it working but there are some some exceptions like (Chrome Console):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/fonts/slick.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/ajax-loader.gif
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/fonts/slick.ttf
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/fonts/slick.svg#slick
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the exact same thing as well. I was using gulp and bower to give me the Slick Carousel plugin. I believe gulp and grunt are in many ways similar. Unfortunately, it's the plugin that's making the call for these files and it's 404'ing because its relative urls were no longer pointing to the right place because of how gulp/grunt compiled them and injected them into dist/.

Here's how I solved it. I copied and pasted only these URLS from slick.scss in bower component that was making the call and made a new file and saved it in my src/ folder. I uploaded all these files to a host. I changed these relative URLs to absolute URLs (to point to the hosted files), so to override the relative urls making the call.

Let me know this solved your problem. I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like grunt build any CSS inside the final version, even if is not used. I had a main.scss file which i never import but it was that file style that was messing with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I'm not able to add a comment as my reputation isn't high enough yet. So I was going to ask if you were using angular-fullstack generator. I had a similar error when I was working with this generator. I never could determine the exact cause...except that it has to deal with the `<!-- injector:js -->` I spent hours looking into it. Basically for a quick solution I recopied the index.html page from the default build and then I made sure to never touch anything below the Google analytics line. For some reason when I even changed the tabs or spacing I started to get this error. the problem is that your script files are not getting injected into the app.js dist file that is minified and ulgified.

Of course in your example it looks like it's not really your js files that are an issue but that some of the other files aren't getting copied over correctly.I'm about to post a question that kind of deals with a similar issue, except it is dealing with the bower_components, so I'll link it later in case it helps you at all.

Comment: I'm not using angular-fullstack generator, but i found two things:

1. Any CSS in the styles folder will be added to the final style file,probably overwriting some settings if there are any CSS files you don't use explicitly.

2. HTML Integrity is very important, if there is one unclosed tag it can end up in messy stuff

Maybe your problem has to be with the second one, i'm currently using html-angular-validate https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-html-angular-validate to check my HTML files.

I guess that if there would be a problem with the injector none of the controllers would work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the Grunt File where the Copy option is there you can see the components copied at the grunt serve:dist command see src:[...

```
 copy:
        dist:
            files: [
                expand: true
                dot: true
                cwd: "<%= yeoman.app %>"
                dest: "<%= yeoman.dist %>"
                src: [
                    "favicon.ico"
                    # bower components that has image, font dependencies
                    "bower_components/font-awesome/css/*"
                    "bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/*"
                    "bower_components/weather-icons/css/*"
                    "bower_components/weather-icons/fonts/*"
                    "bower_components/weather-icons/font/*"

                    "fonts/**/*"
                    "i18n/**/*"
                    "images/**/*"
                    # "styles/bootstrap/**/*"
                    "styles/fonts/**/*"
                    "styles/img/**/*"
                    "styles/ui/images/*"
                    "views/**/*"
                ]
            ,
                expand: true
                cwd: ".tmp"
                dest: "<%= yeoman.dist %>"
                src: ["styles/**", "assets/**"]
            ,
                expand: true
                cwd: ".tmp/images"
                dest: "<%= yeoman.dist %>/images"
                src: ["generated/*"]
            ]
```

the make sure you have a copy of the components on your dist package